# MVVM: On changing Object info by clicking the respective item in the ViewHolder, screen goes to the top of the RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, listadapter

In onCreate method of the Activity I have an observer:

```
    viewModel.getLearnedWords().observe(this, learnedWords -> adapter.submitList(learnedWords));

    adapter = new ArchiveAdapter(new ArchiveAdapter.ArchiveDiff(), this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    //other parts of the code
```

My adapter extends ListAdapter:

```
public class ArchiveAdapter extends ListAdapter<Word, ArchiveAdapter.ArchiveViewHolder> {
// ...
```

SwitchButton is in ViewHolder, when I change the position of it - it triggers the method which updates the content of the item:

In ViewHoler:

```
holder.btnSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
        if (isChecked) {
            mSwitchListener.onSwitchChange(currentWord, true);
        } else {
            mSwitchListener.onSwitchChange(currentWord, false);
        }
    });
```

in Activity:

```
@Override
public void onSwitchChange(Word word, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        word.setCategory(18);
    } else {
        word.setCategory(19);
    }
    viewModel.update(word); //method in Activity which is triggered by SwitchButton in the ViewHolder
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ArchiveViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private WordRepo mRepo;
    private LiveData<List<Word>> mLearnedWords;

    public ArchiveViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepo = new WordRepo(application);
        mLearnedWords = mRepo.getLearnedWords();
    }

    LiveData<List<Word>> getLearnedWords() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getLearnedWords: called");
        return mLearnedWords;
    }

    public void update(Word word) {
        mRepo.update(word);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, yet the problem is that when I switch the button, my screen goes back to the top of the recyclerview (maybe adapter is reloaded?). The list contains more than 1000 items, and it is very inconvinient.

Where is the cause of this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: could you update the question by posting your view model? especially `update(word)` of your view model

Comment: yes, I've done it

Comment: How do you mean "my screen goes back to the top"? Scroll to top or...? In that case can you please post submitList method...

Comment: @AlexRodionow every time you update some item in the list, `update(word)` of your viewmodel triggers resulting in the underlying database to be updated and since `mRepo.getLearnedWords()` attaches an observer on the database, the update just propagates resulting in triggering `viewModel.getLearnedWords()` thereby reloading the adapter with new data

Comment: add a `Log` statement in ` viewModel.getLearnedWords()` to see if adapter is indeed loading with new data

Comment: Thanks for this information. I added the  ```Log``` statement there (and I updated my question likewise) , and this debug-tag is shown only on the first opening of the Activity, but not on changing of the position of switchbutton